# Custom Filter AdminJS (Component + Action)

Tags: adminjs

I am trying to create a custom filter. I am on a table and want to sort according to fields on another table. ManyToMany relation between tables.

I also need to create a custom filter component, with matching design.

After a day of work, my working solution is in the answer, so if you have the same issue, it will save you time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution :

I linked the component from the ResourceOptions in the components section within a custom component who had already a customer list bundle :

```
filter: AdminJS.bundle("../../components/generic/filter/FilterSublist"),
```

Here is the custom style :

```js
//style so your custom components looks like the basic AdminJS component
const customStyles = {
  menu: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    borderRadius: 0,
    backgroundColor: "#343F87",
  }),

  control: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    backgroundColor: "#343F87",
    borderRadius: 0,
    border: '1px solid #525C99',
  }),

  option: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: '#2E3974',
    },
    backgroundColor: "#343F87",
  }),
}
```

Here is the component :

```js
import {BasePropertyComponent, BasePropertyProps, ApiClient, useRecord} from "adminjs";
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const FilterSublist = (props: BasePropertyProps) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState<Array<{label: string, value: any}>>([]);
  const [defaultOptions, setDefaultOptions] = useState<Array<{label: string, value: any}>>([]);
  const api = new ApiClient()

  useEffect(() => {handleGetDefaultValues()}, [])

  const handleGetDefaultValues = async () => {
    const searchResults = await api.searchRecords({resourceId: "ServiceProviderAreaOfAction", query: ""})
    const filteredResults = searchResults.filter(r => r.params.id !== Number(values))
    setDefaultOptions(filteredResults.map(v => ({label: v.title, value: v.params.id})))
  }

  const handleSearch = async (inputValue: string, callback: (options: Array<{ label: string, value: any }>) => void) => {
    const searchResults = await api.searchRecords({resourceId: "ServiceProviderAreaOfAction", query: inputValue})
    const filteredResults = searchResults.filter(r => !values.map(v => Number(v.value.id)).includes(Number(r.params.id)))
    callback(filteredResults.map(v => ({label: v.title, value: v.params.id})))
  }

  //Store values in props.filter so they are sent with all the filters
  const handleChange = (a: Array<{label: string, value: any}>) => {
    setValues(a ? a : [])
      // @ts-ignore
      props.onChange(props.property.propertyPath, (a ? a.map(e => e.value).join(',') : undefined))
  }

  return (
    <div style={{marginBottom: 18}}>
      <p style={{fontSize: 12, marginBottom: 8}}>Area of action</p>
      {/* @ts-ignore */}
      <AsyncSelect className="AsyncSelectBlue" isMulti defaultOptions={defaultOptions} value={values} onChange={handleChange} loadOptions={handleSearch} styles={customStyles}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FilterSublist
```

In the ResourceOptions again, I used a custom handler to list actions, and in that handler, I detected the custom filter, transformed it to an array of id, then deleted the custom filter field, let the normal filter do his job, and filtered the result with the array of id.

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

**More convenient and actula information**
To simplify your life, I've found everything you need to easily rewrite the entire adminjs as you see fit.

**First:**
These are the direct methods for overwriting/adding adminjs components.

```js
    import { ComponentLoader, OverridableComponent } from 'adminjs';

    export const componentLoader = new ComponentLoader();

    /**
     * Helpers
     */
    export const add = (url: string, componentName: string): string => componentLoader.add(componentName, url);

    export const override = (url: string, componentName: OverridableComponent): string =>
        componentLoader.override(componentName, url);

    /**
     * Overridable components
     */
    override('components/top-bar', 'Version');
    override('components/login', 'Login');
    override('components/sidebar-resource-section', 'SidebarResourceSection');

    /**
     * Common components
     */
    export const Components = {
        Editor: add('./components/Editor/index', 'Editor'),
    };

    /**
     * Pages
     */
    export const CUSTOM_PAGE = add('pages/custom-page', 'CustomPage');
    export const DESIGN_SYSTEM_PAGE = add('pages/design-system-examples/index', 'DesignSystemPage');
```

In the "OverridableComponent" type, you can find all the parts of the application that you can override, including "FilterDrawer", which looks something like this:

```js
export type OverridableComponent =
  | 'LoggedIn'
  | 'NoRecords'
  | 'SidebarResourceSection'
  | 'SidebarFooter'
  | 'SidebarBranding'
  | 'Sidebar'
  | 'Breadcrumbs'
  | 'FilterDrawer'
  ...
```

With these types, you can override both specific elements within the "FilterDrawer" and the entire "FilterDrawer" altogether. For instance, instead of completely revamping the UI of the "FilterDrawer" to avoid redefining its logic entirely, you can opt to replace only specific parts of the form. For instance, by utilizing the "DefaultDatetimeFilterProperty" type, you can substitute the DatePicker component within the filter form. Similarly, the same principle applies to the "Sidebar"; you can overwrite its footer simply by using "SidebarFooter", and so forth.

[Source code](https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/adminjs-example-app/blob/master/src/admin/components.bundler.ts)

To make it easier for you to adapt in writing your custom Filters drawer, I recommend taking a look at this [source code](https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/adminjs/blob/master/src/frontend/components/app/filter-drawer.tsx) (this is how it's implemented under the hood of adminjs):

```js
import { Box, Button, Drawer, DrawerContent, DrawerFooter, H3, Icon } from '@adminjs/design-system'
import isNil from 'lodash/isNil.js'
import pickBy from 'lodash/pickBy.js'
import React, { FormEventHandler, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

import allowOverride from '../../hoc/allow-override.js'
import { useTranslation } from '../../hooks/index.js'
import { useFilterDrawer } from '../../hooks/use-filter-drawer.js'
import { useQueryParams } from '../../hooks/use-query-params.js'
import { RecordJSON, ResourceJSON } from '../../interfaces/index.js'
import { getResourceElementCss } from '../../utils/index.js'
import BasePropertyComponent from '../property-type/index.js'

export type FilterProps = {
  resource: ResourceJSON
}

type MatchProps = {
  resourceId: string
}

const FilterDrawer: React.FC<FilterProps> = (props) => {
  const { resource } = props
  const properties = resource.filterProperties

  const [filter, setFilter] = useState<Record<string, unknown>>({})
  const params = useParams<MatchProps>()
  const { translateButton, translateLabel } = useTranslation()
  const initialLoad = useRef(true)
  const { isVisible, toggleFilter } = useFilterDrawer()
  const { storeParams, clearParams, filters } = useQueryParams()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialLoad.current) {
      initialLoad.current = false
    } else {
      setFilter({})
    }
  }, [params.resourceId])

  const handleSubmit: FormEventHandler<HTMLElement> = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    storeParams({ filters: pickBy(filter, (v) => !isNil(v)), page: '1' })
  }

  const handleReset: FormEventHandler<HTMLElement> = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    clearParams('filters')
    setFilter({})
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (filters) {
      setFilter(filters)
    }
  }, [filters])

  const handleChange = (propertyName: string | RecordJSON, value: any): void => {
    if ((propertyName as RecordJSON).params) {
      throw new Error('you can not pass RecordJSON to filters')
    }
    setFilter({
      ...filter,
      [propertyName as string]: typeof value === 'string' && !value.length ? undefined : value,
    })
  }

  const contentTag = getResourceElementCss(resource.id, 'filter-drawer')
  const cssContent = getResourceElementCss(resource.id, 'filter-drawer-content')
  const cssFooter = getResourceElementCss(resource.id, 'filter-drawer-footer')
  const cssButtonApply = getResourceElementCss(resource.id, 'filter-drawer-button-apply')
  const cssButtonReset = getResourceElementCss(resource.id, 'filter-drawer-button-reset')

  return (
    <Drawer
      variant="filter"
      isHidden={!isVisible}
      as="form"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      onReset={handleReset}
      data-css={contentTag}
    >
      <DrawerContent data-css={cssContent}>
        <Box flex justifyContent="space-between">
          <H3>{translateLabel('filters', resource.id)}</H3>
          <Button
            type="button"
            variant="light"
            size="icon"
            rounded
            color="text"
            onClick={toggleFilter}
          >
            <Icon icon="X" />
          </Button>
        </Box>
        <Box my="x3">
          {properties.map((property) => (
            <BasePropertyComponent
              key={property.propertyPath}
              where="filter"
              onChange={handleChange}
              property={property}
              filter={filter}
              resource={resource}
            />
          ))}
        </Box>
      </DrawerContent>
      <DrawerFooter data-css={cssFooter}>
        <Button type="button" variant="light" onClick={handleReset} data-css={cssButtonReset}>
          {translateButton('resetFilter', resource.id)}
        </Button>
        <Button type="submit" variant="contained" data-css={cssButtonApply}>
          {translateButton('applyChanges', resource.id)}
        </Button>
      </DrawerFooter>
    </Drawer>
  )
}

const OverridableFilterDrawer = allowOverride(FilterDrawer, 'FilterDrawer')

export {
  OverridableFilterDrawer as default,
  OverridableFilterDrawer as FilterDrawer,
  FilterDrawer as OriginalFilterDrawer,
}
```

Help yourself!